# AngularJS update form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have user data fetched from database and stored into my `$rootScope.currentUser`
I want to pass those data to the update-form so the user can see old values an update them.
I want that the users' updates does not affect my `$rootScope.currentUser` so I can keep old values

I tried to achieve that throught 2 solutions:

1) Using `ng-model="currentUser.name"` ...
=> Thats affect the $rootScope, every change in the form change automatically $rootScope values

2) Using `ng-values="currentUser.name"` and `ng-model="updatedUser.name"` on the same input
=> Thats does not affect the $rootScope BUT the form validation is considering the form as empty since updatedUser(the model) doesn't have a default value onload !!
(Also ng-value doesn't work with textArea !! I don't know why!)

So, anyway, what is the best solution to achieve that?!

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It looks that you want to bind $rootScope with input control but don't want to change it. Am I right?

Comment: @Pooja-G Yes! exactly

Comment: @MehdiGuelloub I think you got the answer..  use angular.copy()

Comment: "`$rootScope.currentUser`"  Eek.  It's very bad practice to use root scope as a data dump -- this is the Angular equivalent of using global variables.  Keep your data encapsulated in directives (for single use) or services/factories (for data that needs to be shared across multiple parts of your app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you retrieve the existing user, just do something like this in your controller that controls the edit:

```
function myController($scope, $rootScope) {

    // make a copy of the current user
    $scope.editUser = angular.copy($rootScope.currentUser);

    $scope.save = function() {
        // save copy of edited in rootscope
        $rootScope.currentUser = angular.copy($scope.editUser);
    }
}
```

Then in your form:

```
<form ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text"
           ng-model="editUser.name" />
    <button type="button"
            ng-click="save()">Save</button>
</form>
```

See also [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dm8121q7/)

Comment: if the currentUser is a deep object, he might need `angular.merge`

Comment: Why? It does not have to merge, only be copied over.

Comment: copy make a shallow copy, meaning, reference of subfields won't be clone, they will be kept as is. Merge perform a deep copy. As i said it's only if his `currentUser` object has more than one level.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the user object

```
updatedUser = angular.copy(currentUser);
```

and use

```
ng-model="updatedUser"
```

which then is initialised with the old values